# Diferences between photoelectric effect and the Compton effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Could anyone explain the differences between the photoelectric effect and the Compton effect in a complete but perceptible form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out this answer [Compton scattering vs. photoelectric effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31581/compton-scattering-vs-photoelectric-effect)

But the gist of it is that the Photoelectric effect occurs at low energies for bounded electrons, resulting in the ionization of the electrons. The key thing in the Photoelectric effect is that it does not depend the intensity of light but rather the energy of the photons.

Where as Compton Scattering occurs at high energies on free electrons, where the photon scatters off of an electron imparting some of it's momentum on to an electron, and since $c = f\lambda$  and $E = hf = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$ so after imparting its momentum the photon loses some of its energy since $h$ is a constant its frequency $f$ will decrease thus its wave length $\lambda$ will increase as it is inversely proportional to the frequency.

Also see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_energy

Comment: But in Compton's effect are the electrons ejected, or does this only occur in the photoelectric effect?

Comment: They can be ejected in both scenarios but Compton scattering is a form of inelastic scattering